# Auto as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, auto, template-argument-deduction

```
template<typename> struct CL{};

CL<char> fnc();

int main()
{
    CL<auto> cl=fnc(); //error
}
```

Why isn't it correct? What's problem to deduce auto as char?

Comment: The syntax doesn't allow `auto` to appear in this spot. Just make it `auto cl = fnc();` and have `auto` be deduced to `CL<char>`.

Comment: You may need to enable the [Concepts TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf) for this syntax to work. (That is, you'll also need a compiler that implements the Concepts TS. And you probably need to wait for the Concepts TS to be published.)

Comment: `auto` is not a type.